# make apache send header 401 unless a parameter is present

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have a rest api that has to be executed only if the parameter "manual" is present in the request.

I tried with a RedirectMatch directive inside the virtualhost declaration

```
    RedirectMatch 401 "^\/api\/file\.php\?.*(?!manual).*$
```

but it does not work. Actually seems that none of the last part of the regexp works.

EDIT:
Umh, I just found out that RedirectMatch directive does not match against the query part of the get request...

Comment: RedirectMatch doesn't match against the query part.  You may simply have to do this in your server software by returning an HTTP response code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I can do it with mod_rewrite:

```
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/file\.php$ [NC]
      RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  !^.*\&manual=.*$ [NC]
      RewriteRule ^/api/file\.php - [R=401]
```

It seems working well so far ;)